# Remove folder name from URL

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a domain www.domain.com redirected to / in my server.

Next I have index.php whith code:

```
header("Location: http://domain.com/v3/");
```

When I enter mydomain.com I have mydomain.com/v3/ in url.

How to remove v3 from Url

Comment: You can't remove anything from URL, if you do then your browser will just take you there. I think you should remove `v3/` from your URL and check if the problem is resolved, as I tried to understand it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `header` line from your PHP code since it is doing a redirect and have this lookahead based rule in your root `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+v3/([^?\s]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^((?!v3/).*)$ /v3/$1 [L,NC]
```

Which basically means if request is not starting with `/v3/` forward to `/v3/` without changing the URL in browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you're redirecting from PHP, you can use [parse_url](http://php.net/parse_url) to clean it up.

```
$url = "http://domain.com/v3/";

$host = parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_HOST); 
$scheme = parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_SCHEME); 

header( $scheme . '://' . $host );
```